# Can HttpClient share same the HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID as its host?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

There are times when I want to make calls with the HTTPClient from within my ASP.NET Web Site to internal resources ( ASP.NET Webforms and MVC running together).

The first hurdle was the forms auth cookie, which I think I solved, the second problem though is that when I call my MVC controller, the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID is different than when I initiated the call. The SessionID is being used as a key to cache items, thus the items come back null in the controller.

So my question boils down to this, did I implement the cookie swapping correctly and can the httpClient inherit the session from it's host if it has one?

```
try
{
    // Boostrap the properties tab by preloading data
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    string resource = string.Format("/Contact/PropertyBootstrapper/{0}", Request.Params["ContactGuid"]);             
    HttpCookie appCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        Debug.Assert(appCookie != null, "appCookie != null");
        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie(appCookie.Name,appCookie.Value));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(resource).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(exception);
}
```

Comment: You just do the same with the session cookie - copy from the context to the client.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Can you write an answer, I'll accept it then. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do the same with the session cookie - copy from the context to the client. The session cookie carries the CookieID.

Comment: Don't know why it didn't dawn on me that it was another cookie, but you're right adding it the the request worked like a champ. Thank you.. Stephen